# attribute binding and ng directive cause unrendered webpage

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I am learning Angular and I follow the directions and guidance stated in the [following tutorial](https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/interpolation-in-angular/).

The problem I am facing is, that when I run

```
ng serve --open
```

I do not see the items displayed on the page on the http://localhost:4200/, but I got the page shown in the screenshot below instead.

I expect to see the items displayed as the code posted below implies.

Please let me know where my mistake is and how to fix it so I can see the list of items displayed on the webpage.

**app.component.ts**:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class item {
  code: number;
  name: string;

  constructor(code: number, name: string) {
    this.code = code;
    this.name = name;
  }

   items = [
    new item(1, 'Mobile'),
    new item(1, 'Laptop'),
    new item(1, 'Desktop'),
    new item(1, 'Printer')
  ]
}
```

**app.component.html**:

```
<p>item</p>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor = "let d of items">
    <p>{{d.code}}</p>
    <p>{{d.name}}</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**image**:

[image]

Comment: FYI the page you are viewing is the one auto-generated by the CLI. You had some code in app.component.html, which you deleted to input yours, right? That code is the one that was responsible for the page you are seeing. I wonder why you still see it at this point... did you save? anyway, your code has errors, as pointed out in the answer from N.F.      
(P.S.: it's always a good idea to check the console for errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do like this.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

export class item {
  code: number;
  name: string;

  constructor(code: number, name: string) {
    this.code = code;
    this.name = name;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  items = [
    new item(1, 'Mobile'),
    new item(1, 'Laptop'),
    new item(1, 'Desktop'),
    new item(1, 'Printer')
  ]

  constructor() {}
}
```